# Jenkins build how to get docker images

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I have EKS cluster setup with single managed node group its contains two (worker ec2 VM). I deployed Jenkins inside the k8s cluster its is up and running without any issue.

Note: in Jenkins - configure system - cloud - k8 specification - Kubernetes URL - I placed my master address where my EKS cluster is running Kubernetes control plane is running at  https://eksendpoint.eu-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com and also connection test is successful.

[image: k8s cloud configuration]

Next when I'm running Jenkins build creating Jenkins build pod and once the build is completed Jenkins build pod also getting terminated automatically.

Note: In Jenkins I have only single node master and there is no salve. when jenkins file create Docker image using below code and also image successfully tagged with based my code.

Now the question is after building Docker image where should i get the Docker images to deploy into my k8s environment. Note: I'm not using any Docker registry container to upload my docker images in this case how do i get my Docker images.

```
 stage('Build Docker Image') {
      container('docker') {
        echo 'docker'
        sh "docker build --network=host -t myimage:mytag ."
        sh 'pwd'
        sh 'ls -lrt'
        sh 'docker images'
        sh 'hostname'
      }
    }
```

Jenkins logs output

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker images
+ grep devops
myimage/mytag                  build-12345      8b1c58dcc39d   3 seconds ago       583MB

[Pipeline] sh
+ hostname
worker23cc8b1c0-c6b0-415b-b0e9-f23186ca39e8-xsm58-z7wmk
```

Comment: You have to tag & push your image to a docker registry that your EKS cluster can access (for example Amazon ECR). You then have to register credentials to your ECR in your k8s cluster. Jenkins builds the image in its "local" registry so your EKS cluster probably won't know that registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kubernetes resources specifying a container image to be run inside of pods expect the image to be available in a container image registry. it is not possible to create pods with images not available in an image registry.